# Whats wrong with my decimal to binary converter?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, converters

I have to create a decimal to binary converter without using lists yet my code is giving my wrong values and I can't figure out why.

```
def DecToBin(val):
    bine = 128
    counter = 8
    coded = 10
    binary = 0
    while val > 0 and bine != 0.5:
        if val < bine:
            bine = bine/2
            counter -= 1
        elif val > bine:
            val = val - bine
            binary = binary + (coded ^ counter)
            counter -= 1
            bine = bine/2
        elif val == bine:
            binary = binary + (coded ^ counter)
            counter = 0
            val = 0
    return binary
```

When the value input is 3 it gives me 19.

Comment: Your title says binary -> decimal but your method name says decimal -> binary. Which is it?

Comment: Yh my bad its decimal to binary

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. First, the python power operator is `**` not `^`. Second, `bine` should be 256, not 128 given your counter value. Your code should look like this:

```
def DecToBin(val):
    bine = 256
    counter = 8
    coded = 10
    binary = 0
    while val > 0 and bine != 0.5:
        if val < bine:
            bine = bine/2
            counter -= 1
        elif val > bine:
            val = val - bine
            binary = binary + (coded ** counter)
            counter -= 1
            bine = bine/2
        elif val == bine:
            binary = binary + (coded ** counter)
            counter = 0
            val = 0
    return binary
```

Comment: Also note that this will only work for decimal values less or equal to 256. I would recommend changing `bine = 128` to `bine = 2**32` and `counter = 8` to `counter = 32`